# Code to detect if a line in a file is unicode: TypeError: String argument without encoding

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

This issue started with thinking the output of a different program was giving unicode so original file must be unicode. We know what assuming things does. So I decided to go back and just try to detect what kind of encoding the file has in case it is not unicode. I know it is not 100% but I just have a hunch that the original file is not encoded at all and the other program is doing something.

I've tried using just a straight conversion that would lose characters sometimes and decided to find out if it was even encoded to begin with.

```
import glob
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

detector = UniversalDetector()
files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\name\Documents\folder\*.txt')

for filename in files:
    print (filename.ljust(60))
    detector.reset()
    for line in filename:
        detector.feed(line)
        if detector.done: break
    detector.close()
    print (detector.result)
```

C:\Users\name\Documents\folder\RTAMPS_72393_WS0000L03611O1D_BIG9_2013_12_27_11_42_28_unicodeTest.txt

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-50926a0bce8d> in <module>
      9     detector.reset()
     10     for line in filename:
---> 11         detector.feed(line)
     12         if detector.done: break
     13     detector.close()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chardet\universaldetector.py in feed(self, byte_str)
    130 
    131         if not isinstance(byte_str, bytearray):
--> 132             byte_str = bytearray(byte_str)
    133 
    134         # First check for known BOMs, since these are guaranteed to be correct
```

TypeError: string argument without an encoding

This makes me think that the line in the file isn't encoded at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are feeding it the *name of the file* ... see [the documentation:](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/chardet/universaldetector.html)

> ```
> def feed(self, byte_str):
>     """
>     Takes a chunk of a document and feeds it through all of the relevant
>     charset probers.
>
>     After calling ``feed``, you can check the value of the ``done``
>     attribute to see if you need to continue feeding the
>     ``UniversalDetector`` more data, or if it has made a prediction
>     (in the ``result`` attribute).
>
>     .. note::
>        You should always call ``close`` when you're done feeding in your
>        document if ``done`` is not already ``True``.
>     """
> ```

You are supposed to feed it **the files content** - not the name to a file.

Adapted from https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html:

```
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

with open("yourfile.txt", "rb") as myfile:   # read as binary - is read in textmode else 
    detector = UniversalDetector()
    for line in myfile:
        detector.feed(line)
        if detector.done: break
    detector.close()

print(detector.result)
```

Comment: I did this exact thing when I got the time. I still got the same result. I avoided trying to run over a directory and used only one file. The exact file first.

Comment: It seems the `detector.feed()` expects `bytes`, not `str`. You need to open the file in binary mode: `with open(filename, 'rb') as myfile:`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you two. For puzzle sake, it was not encoded the way I thought it was originally and thus made this check very relevant to the problem!